# Problems Estimating Parameters for the Inverse Gamma Distribution

Tags: distributions, inverse-gamma-distribution

I am trying to estimate the parameters of an inverse gamma distribution such that a given amount of probability mass lies above and below some specified threshold.

If $x$ is an inverse gamma distributed random variable $x \sim \mathrm{Inverse Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$, I want to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that:

$
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a} dx = r
$

and

$
\displaystyle\int_{b}^{\infty} dx = r
$

I have attempted to solve the system of equations:

$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi_{IG}(a| \alpha, \beta) - r = 0 \\
(1 - \Phi_{IG}(b| \alpha, \beta)) - r = 0
\end{aligned}
$

With $\Phi_{IG}$ being the Inverse Gamma CDF, but the solution obtained using scipy's nonlinear root finding module appears extremely sensitive to the initial guess and I am not aware of a principled means of determining it.

---

**My Question:**

Is there a principled method of determining *initial* values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to solve the problem in such a way? Are there more effective ways of identifying $\alpha$ and $\beta$ other than solving such a system of equations?

**Additional Information**

It appears my problem primarily occurs when initial values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ fail to allocate *any* mass below/above $a$ and $b$, respectively, in which case the objective function described by the above system of equations is effectively flat on initialisation and no progress can be made.